# How to get data before reloadData in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

I use AFNetworking to get data from the server. But my tableView updates before I get data every time even though I `reloadData()` in main thread.

Here is my code:

```
class ListTableViewController {
    var manager: AFHTTPSessionManager!
    var title: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //init manager and parameters
        //.......
        manager.get("http://localhost:8080/Router.php", parameters: parameters, progress: nil, success: { task, responseObject in
            let data = responseObject as!Dictionary<String, String>
            self.title = data["title"]!
            self.tableView.reloadData()}, failure: nil)
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }    

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return title
    }

}
```

It will terminate because title is nil.
I'm sure that data is correct because I can display it by `UIAlertController`. But how can I get it before tableView begin to initialize?

Comment: Why is `title` optional at all? Just declare it `var title = ""` or at least declare it as regular optional (`?`)

Comment: @Qyy use completionHandler -After get success response  reload tableView.

Comment: If you want title to be an optional, then change the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?` to `return title ?? "Loading..."` would work as well.  You could then also use the same type of thing in `override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int` function as well, `return title == nil ? 0 : 1` and it wouldn't display anything in the tableView until the data was retreived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table will load automatically when the view controller first appears. This will happen long before your call to `manager.get` completes.

Since you declared `title` as an implicitly unwrapped optional value with no initial value, accessing it causes the crash.

Simply change:

```
var title: String!
```

to:

```
var title = "Loading..." // or just ""
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've understood.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at the first reload which happens when the vc is iniiated title is nil

```
var title: String!
```

so change it to any thing either in `viewDidLoad`

```
title = ""
```

or

```
var title = "anything"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that both @Sh_Khan and @rmaddy answers are both correct and great, but another way to do it would be to use the `var title:String?` as a way to tell when the data is loaded.  By using it as an optional, you can tell that the values have not been loaded yet.  For example:

```
class ListTableViewController {
    //...
    var title: String?
    var isLoaded:Bool { get { return self.title != nil } }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //init manager and parameters
        .......
        manager.get("http://localhost:8080/Router.php", parameters: parameters, progress: nil, success: {task, responseObject in
            if let data = responseObject as? Dictionary<String, String> {
                self.title = data["title"]
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        },failure: nil)
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
         return self.isLoaded ? 1 : 0
    }    

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return title ?? ""
    }

    //...
}
```

Please note that I changed your closure on the `manager.get` function because forcing the unwrap of `responseObject` will lead to crashes as well.

Comment: The whole point of using an implicitly unwrapped optional is you will actually give it a value before any code needs to get its value and there is no need to check if it's nil or not. If you want to use `return title ?? ""` then declare `title` as `var title: String?`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think using it as an optional is more appropriate when I get a data array. if I change 'title' to 'titles[]', using "titles: [String]?" is more suitable than "titles = [String](repeating: "", count: 100)", right?